# How to configure nightlight to run for the whole day?

Tags: switchboard, nightlight

What values should the "From" and "To" fields have in manual mode to run it for the whole day?
I tried 12:00AM to 12:00AM which did not work. I then tried 12:00AM to 11:59PM, but the "To" field keeps resetting back to 11:00PM

Edit: Looks like this was reported long back, but no action taken so far https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel-indicator-nightlight/issues/32

Answer (score 1):

I see what you're talking about. It *seems* like it's resetting back to 11:00 PM, but once you click off the time setting, it should be set to 11:59 PM.

**UPDATE:**
After clarifying things with Rajiv, this does appear to be a bug.  After setting to 11:59 PM, closing the Settings window and re-opening, the time reverts to 11:00 PM.

I checked the elementary OS github page and there is a request to use Night Light all day:
https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel-indicator-nightlight/issues/32

Updated demo of the issue:

[image]

Comment: Does it stay at 11:59 PM even after you quit and reopen the "systems settings" application?

Comment: You are correct. After closing System Settings window and opening it back up, it says 11:00 PM.